# Numpy where not giving expected shape

Tags: python, numpy

The problem is fairly simple.  Given a 256x256 grayscale image, I want to return a color image with colors based on a threshold.

So I'm thinking:

```
img=whatever # 2D array of floats representing grayscale image
threshold=0.5
color1=[1.0,0.0,0.0]
color2=[0.0,0.0,1.0]
newImg=np.where(img>threshold,color1,color2)
```

Yet I get the infamous:
"ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (500,500) (3,) (3,)"

Huh?  I was really expecting that to give an array shaped (500,500,3). Why didn't it combine them??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how `numpy.where` works. It looks like you might be thinking that for True cells of `img>threshold`, `where` picks the entirety of `color1` as a value, and for False cells, it picks the entirety of `color2`. Whatever it was you were thinking, that's not how it works.

`numpy.where` [broadcasts](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the arguments together, and then for each cell of the first argument, picks the *corresponding cell* of either the second or third argument. To produce a shape-(500, 500, 3) result, the arguments would have to broadcast together to a shape of (500, 500, 3). Your inputs aren't broadcasting-compatible with each other at all.

One way to make the broadcasting work would be to add an extra length-1 dimension to the end of `img>threshold`:

```
newImg=np.where((img>threshold)[..., None],color1,color2)
```

If you're new to broadcasting, it may help to use [`numpy.broadcast_arrays`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_arrays.html#numpy.broadcast_arrays) to see what the result of broadcasting multiple arrays together looks like.

Comment: "Whatever it was you were thinking, that's not how it works."  Story of my life, lol.

That certainly explains the problem though.

I wonder, would it make sense to broadcast the colors as the same shape as img?
    
This seems to work:

    shape=(img.shape[0],img.shape[1],len(color1))
    newImg=np.where(img>threshold,broadcast_to(color1,shape),broadcast_to(color2,shape))

Comment: @TheHeadlessSourceMan: You can't broadcast them to the same shape as `img`. You're broadcasting them to a different shape, which [still isn't broadcasting-compatible with the mask](https://ideone.com/KBuhKw).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I realize that I originally misinterpreted the original array dimensions as user2357112 pointed out.

To add an additional solution to your original problem that does not require numpy, use:

```
newImg = [[color1 if (cell > threshold) else color2 for cell in row] for row in img]
```

Comment: The list for `threshold` has nothing to do with it. Unlike the question, your `img` is a 3-dimensional, 3x3x3 array, rather than 2-dimensional, 500x500.

Comment: @user2357112 
Yes, I did  misinterpret the array dimensions.